# running command line in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

my command prompt is pointing to c:\users\myname directory . My program is location at C:\ETL\Shredding.exe . How shall I write the command line in batch file to run shredding.exe from this location?

Comment: Write it exactly as you have it in your question.  `c:\ETL\Shredding.exe "arg"` etc.  You don't have to have the working directory be the same as the program you're executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the directory to be whatever you like within your batch file like so:

```
cd %DIRECTORY I WANT%
```

Alternatively, you can simply specify the full filepath of whichever program you want to run.

As [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) also said, you can use `pushd directoryname` if you want to be able to revert back to the original working directory later, after which you can use `popd` when you want to go return to the directory.

Comment: also, `pushd directoryname` if you want to be able to revert back to the original working directory later -- then `popd` when you want to go back.

Comment: You might also be interested to know [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15656927/1683264), if you don't already.