# Temporarily set Environment variables with batch file

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, catalina

I'd like temporarily set Environment variables like Catalina and Java_Home using a batch file, without making persistent changes.

Changes should be removed after the execution of a web-page.

There's a way to do it?

Comment: All variables you create in a batch file are volatile when using the SET command.  They will all disappear after the batch file closes.

Comment: Well, after the command prompt that had the script running in it closes (just in case you ran the script from the command line instead of double-clicking it).

Comment: `setlocal` is generally good practice as well.  Changes to variables made within a `setlocal` session are forgotten when the script ends or `endlocal` is encountered.  As a bonus, [`setlocal` also preserves](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659309/1683264) the current working directory.

Comment: Yes. Setlocal/endlocal is a best practice in my book

Answer (score 7):

In your file, at the top, use [setlocal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx), when exiting the file, use [endlocal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490898.aspx).